# How to add App Groups iOS 8 Extension?

Tags: xcode, ios8, ios-extensions

I am having a strange issue: In the project i am working we have to introduce Share extension. The problem i have now is that the app Groups cannot be added.
When i activate it it shows that i have an issue at https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp7tqbv9x6q175i/Screenshot%202015-01-07%2009.56.34.png?dl=0 . If i use a different bundle id for the main app target it works but i must use this bundle id. 
And if i try to add app groups https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pi1n4j8xajngvm/Screenshot%202015-01-07%2010.03.44.png?dl=0 the same error appears but one row up. I tried to change this settings from the provision portal from app IDs, there works and adds it without a problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You can upload your screenshots directly here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so i fixed this issue by going to Provision portal,identifiers->App IDs, your id, edit, app groups enable, edit set app group and save. Now go to provision profile and re-generate all the inactive Provision profiles and download them. After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your App Group ID must be in this format:

> **group.#yourcustombundleid#**

Like this:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response but this isn't the issue i am having. If i don't have any group selected i still receive the first issue.